# WordPress Underscores Theme Jquery Loaded but not Working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, underscores-wp

Im using the underscores theme for wordpress, jquery is loaded, even tested it with this: and i get the Yeah! back however the tabs : [site link](http://edeals.nickritson.co.uk/) doesnt seem to work. the only plugin currently loaded is visual composer however i tested on another theme and the tabs do work on that. would this be a jquery issue or is there something else that would cause the functionality to stop working?

tried running a straight copy theme of underscores and the tabs work so it has to be something i have added to my version built on top of the underscores however, i disabled all the extra scripts i made and set it to only load the originals and still has a problem which has me completely confused. aside from functions and enqueuing is there anything else that could cause this problem?

```
window.onload = function() {
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Yeah!");
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
}
```

Comment: it has an error look at the console `(index):115 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.cookie is not a function`

Comment: i did see that, would that conflict with the functions being loaded? it is something im trying to fix as well, already loaded a js.cookie.js file but that doesnt seem to have fixed it either, not entirely sure whats causing it as theres no other plugins activated that would conflict

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your function part in browser console and it says Yeah!. So jQuery is loaded.

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
    alert("Yeah!");
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("Doesn't Work");
}
```

For missing cookie function try loading [jQuery Cookie plugin.](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Comment: thanks that fixes the cookie error although tabs are still not working =(

Comment: prettyPhoto js is also missing unfortunately. jQuery behaves as if your top js is missing all bottom part will break. so, you need to check in your console. For now you can add prettyPhoto js. Also, if you are not familiar with console, you can install firebug addon in your firefox or simply press F12 for default developer tool which will make it easier for solving errors.

Comment: this is new wasnt there before and ive disabled the plugin that caused it. do have the console but theres no other bugs that i can see which makes it hard to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: also checked the source code, jquery is the first of the js files being loaded into the header, there are no other js files above it so they should be loading fine : http://prntscr.com/b2quks

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue, annoyingly enough had some syntax issues in the footer. thanks for the help.